# Game dev -Finding img sprites coords Haxe + Haxeflixel

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to make a combat system in `haxe` I made my sprites and now I need to find out the uv coordinates for them how do I achieve that ?

Example from my existing code **:**

```
animation.add("lr", [3, 4, 3, 5], 6, false);
animation.add("u", [6, 7, 6, 8], 6, false);
animation.add("d", [0, 1, 0, 2], 6, false);
```

I tried **:**

```
if (FlxG.mouse.justPressed) {
    // Attack code here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haxeflixel's sprite sheet system doesn't use UV coordinates, it assumes all sprites in the sheet are the same size and consistently spaced apart.

Look at the API reference for [FlxSprite.loadGraphic](https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxSprite.html#loadGraphic). The animation [tutorial](https://haxeflixel.com/documentation/sprites-and-animation/) uses that function like this:

```
loadGraphic(AssetPaths.player__png, true, 16, 16);
```

This means the sprites are in a 16x16 grid, and they're indexed from left to right, top to bottom (with the left-most being index 0).

Here's a visual example of how the coordinates map to indices:

[image: One row]

And here's that same sprite, but with two *rows* instead of one:

[image: Two rows]

Compare those indices to the values in the sample code:

```
animation.add("lr", [3, 4, 3, 5], 6, false);
animation.add("u", [6, 7, 6, 8], 6, false);
animation.add("d", [0, 1, 0, 2], 6, false);
```

The second parameter to [add](https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/animation/FlxAnimationController.html#add) is an array of indices that make up the animation.

So to add a punch animation, just put the frames into the existing grid, and reference them using their indices in the overall spritesheet.

As far as implementing a "combat system", that's a more involved thing. If you just want to play an attack animation, you can make it a non-looping animation, and use a [callback function](https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/animation/FlxAnimationController.html#finishCallback) to detect when it ends. Example:

```
//...defined somewhere in your sprite class
var is_punching:Bool = false;

//...somewhere inside your constructor maybe
animation.finishCallback = function(name:String){
    switch(name){
        case "punch-u", "punch-lr", "punch-d":
            is_punching = false;
        default:
            trace("Some other animation finished: " + name);
    }
}

//...somewhere in your update function
if (FlxG.mouse.justPressed && !is_punching) {
    is_punching = true;
     switch (facing)
     {
         case LEFT, RIGHT:
             animation.play("punch-lr");
         case UP:
             animation.play("punch-u");
         case DOWN:
             animation.play("punch-d");
         case _:
     }
}
```

Then you can check if is_punching is true to prevent the player from walking while punching, or to damage an enemy if they collide with the player while they're punching.